# Display a class named Time. (help troubleshooting code)

Tags: java, class, constructor, main-method

I need to design a class named Time. The class needs to contain:

■ Data fields hour, minute, and second that represent a time.

■ A no-arg constructor that creates a Time object for the current time. (The values
of the data fields will represent the current time.)

■ A constructor that constructs a Time object with a specified elapsed time since
midnight, Jan 1, 1970, in milliseconds. (The values of the data fields will represent
this time.)

■ A constructor that constructs a Time object with the specified hour, minute, and
second.

■ Three get methods for the data fields hour, minute, and second, respectively.

■ A method named setTime(long elapseTime) that sets a new time for the
object using the elapsed time.

For this task, I have created the following code:

```
public class Time{
   private int hour;
   private int minute;
   private int second;

   public Time(){
     this(System.currentTimeMillis());
   }

   public Time(long elapseTime){
     long totalSeconds = elapseTime / 1000L;
     this.second = (int)(totalSeconds % 60L);
     long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60L;
     this.minute = (int)(totalMinutes % 60L);
     int totalHours = (int)(totalMinutes / 60L);
     this.hour = (totalHours % 24);
   }

   public String toString() {
     return this.hour + ":" + this.minute + ":" + this.second + " GMT";
   }

   public int getHour() {
     return this.hour;
   }

   public int getMinute() {
     return this.minute;
   }

   public int getSecond() {
     return this.second;
 }
}
```

It compiles fine, but when I go to run it a dialog box pops up that says "No main methods, applets, or MIDlets found in file". Obviously my main method isn't right, but I can't seem to fix it, cause everything I've tried just creates more errors. If anyone could suggest a change to make my code work, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Edit: Yes, I orginally had it thusly:

```
 public class Time{
  public static void main(String args[]){...
```

but that had about a million errors. It seems I have the meat of it, but not the basic beginnings right.

Comment: I'm not seeing a main method in that code...

Comment: It's a valid class. Not every class can be run by itself. If you need to, create another class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` and test the Time class in that main method.

Comment: So you have written the above code yourself but you do not know how to  write the main method.

Comment: No, I did not write the code myself -- this is an intro class, and we're learning basics. The middle was given to us with the expectation of writing and explaining the beginning. We're being introduced to concepts. I'm brand new to Java -- i've barely written anything myself!

Comment: *For this task, I have created the following code*

Comment: I did create some of it -- the incorrect part. Hence the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You either need a main method in the Time class, or a separate class (ie "TimeTester") like this:

```
public class TimeTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Test the default constructor
    Time time = new Time();

    System.out.println("time = " + time);
    System.out.println("time.toHour() " + time.toHour());
    // etc..

    // Test with a supplied value
    Time time2 = new Time(12033312L);
    System.out.println("time2 = " + time2); 
    // etc..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your main method but in java it has to look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Create time and it will pass */
}
```

Every java program needs a main method otherwise the program cannot be started.